# Random ids between limit IDs using RAND() php msql

Tags: php, mysql, random, limit

anyone know about  how to use Random wallpaperid between limit IDs  using RAND() php msql

i use this but its RAND() whole database

```
$sql_wallpaper = "SELECT * FROM wallpaper WHERE RAND()>0.9 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5";
$res_wallpaper = mysql_query($sql_wallpaper);
```

reply please

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
$sql_wallpaper = "SELECT * FROM wallpaper WHERE id>Min AND id<Max ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$res_wallpaper = mysql_query($sql_wallpaper);
```

Comment: I MEAN like that  i need random wallpapers from ID 1 to ID 100 else but using RAND() between ID 1 to 100
 reply